# Possible to have @ in username in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: users

Is it possible to have usernames with @ in them in Ubuntu 14.04? I'm asking as I would like to try this to fix an issue I'm having with a Git username.

Comment: Note: Your question was on topic on Super User, too, so you did not need to delete it there.

Comment: Thanks for that info. However, I guess I shouldn't double-post. Which site would be the most suitable for any similar questions in the future?

Comment: Any of those two sites is fine. Whatever community you feel more comfortable with!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to create a user with the @ sign in their name but it isn't recommended, for example, running the `adduser` command to add a user with an @ sign will throw this error:

```
adduser: Please enter a username matching the regular expression configured
via the NAME_REGEX[_SYSTEM] configuration variable.  Use the `--force-badname'
option to relax this check or reconfigure NAME_REGEX.
```

Which states that you are able to force a bad username with the `--force-badname` flag so a command like this:

```
sudo adduser foo@bar --force-badname
```

Would create the user "foo@bar".